# No interface when starting GUI program

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I have a problem with Intellij Idea. When I do run my code GUI doesn't give me any interface even there are no errors.

Can you please help me?

The code is below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    int count =0;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button;
    JLabel label;

    public GUI(){
        frame=new JFrame();
        button =new JButton("Click me");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        label =new JLabel("Number of Clicks : 0");
        panel =new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("OUR GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void main(String[] args){
        new GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of Clicks : "+count );
    }
}
```

Comment: why new GUI() in your main method?

Comment: Your code works for me once you include static in the declaration of main.

Comment: new GUI() is the constructor to bring up the window

Comment: Jems thank u ...it works finally !!

Comment: you forgot to add `static` to `main` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `public void main(String[] args)` by `public static void main(String[] args)`.
The `main` method in java is always `public static void main(String[] args)`, other headers cannot be your main method.